# Are long mysql transactions (~30 seconds) with only insert queries an issue? (InnoDB)

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, transactions, insert

I'm working on a PHP script that processes files and inserts information about the files into a database.

Specifically, the script processes some info then begins a transaction and inserts it into a table. I then use `lastinsertid` to get the `ID` of the just inserted row, and use that `ID` in processing the associated file. When the processing completes (takes anywhere from 2-30 seconds) I do a few more inserts into other tables and complete the transaction after checking file processing was successful.

So basically the rundown is this:

```
START TRANSACTION

INSERT DATA INTO TABLE 1

PROCESS FILE USING INSERT ID (takes 2-30 seconds)

INSERT DATA INTO TABLE 2

INSERT DATA INTO TABLE 3

INSERT DATA INTO TABLE 4

//VERIFY FILE PROCESSING    
  if ($file_process == true){   
COMMIT   
}   
else{   
ROLLBACK   
}
```

I know that long transactions are to be avoided due to the issues around holding locks for a long time, but what if the transaction only uses inserts. Since inserts only lock the row that is being inserted is this still an issue?

Can someone explain to me the potential "gotchas" that could arise from this situation? I'm pretty sure that if one session's process is taking a long time and another session begins their own process, `session 1`will not block `session 2`, since the processes only deal with inserts. And if `session 1` fails and has to rollback, it will have no impact on `session 2` whatsoever (other than in the database there will be a gap in the auto-incrementing primary IDs but that doesn't matter)

Answer (score 0):

> Since inserts only lock the row that is being inserted is this still an issue?

Not always. If you insert record in details table, master record got locked as well. If you have many relationships, it's quite hard to realize what exactly locked, which in turn may cause deadlocks.

Comment: "If you insert record in details table, master record got locked as well." Can you extrapolate on this? What do you mean by details table vs master record?

Comment: For instance, `CREATE TABLE master(master_id int not null primary key,...); CREATE TABLE detail(detail_id int not null primary key, master_id int not null, constraint FK_detail_master FOREIGN KEY(master_id) REFERENCES master(master_id));`. Then if you insert record in `detail` (say with master_id = 2), the record in `master` table with master_id =2 is also locked.

Comment: I don't have any master detail relationships like this. Am I still at risk?

Comment: @billmalarky: not from that point of view. However, locks are server resources which are not unlimited. Normally, releasing them as soon as possible is a good practice. Just be aware that server may stop processing new requests if it cannot obtain new lock.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hitting 30 seconds of runtime on your database inserts in your PHP script you may run into the ceiling of your max execution time for PHP.

You can alleviate this by changing the time limit programmatically.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

OR

You can modify your php.ini file to change the default. If this becomes an issue I'd recommend modifying for your database calls only so that you don't let runaway scripts unrelated to your database clog up the server's resources.

Comment: Yes I am already handling the other timeout issues. Thank you though!

Comment: @billmalarky No problem :) Just thought I'd bring that up since you had a rather open ended question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not feeling sure about using transactions there, I would recommend you using a `new_added_row` extra column there and if something goes wrong, you'd just delete the `new_added_row=1` columns for rolling back your transaction. You'd still be getting that insert_id, and not using transactions and will be able to rollback the changes. If multiple users would do this asynchronously, you might consider using a `session_key  extra column to prevent deleting other peoples' inserts.

Comment: I'm considering doing the initial insert, then processing the file, then starting a transaction to run all the additional inserts, and then if the file processes correctly and the transaction commits, then keeping the initial insert, and if not deleting the initial insert. The problem with this is sometimes (rarely) the file processing will take too long and timeout (which is desired if it is taking too long) or potentially even crash the scrip by throwing some fatal error, then I've got that bad record sitting in the first table from the initial insert. Thus why I want all in 1 transaction.

Comment: And I am telling you an other way to do that.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your method. How does it help avoid the issue of the script crashing? That is, how will the first insert query that is outside of the other transaction get rolled back or removed if the script crashes or times out?

Comment: delete the new_inserts before running this script and it would be rolled back and then start them again. if the script successfully finishes, delete their new_inserts marks. and set_time_limit(0); command would help you with the timeout. mysql wont be timed out because you won't be using transactions.